# Were we just missed, or did we ask to not graduate?

Tags: discussion

We were well beyond the required 1000 questions to graduate, when the 58 other sites graduated out of Beta recently. The announcement by Stack Exchange said "we allowed the communities to stay in Beta if they didn’t feel ready to leave that state yet". Does that mean that the diamond moderators of Cardano.SE told SE that we didn't feel we were ready?

That's totally okay if you did, but I'm just wondering if that happened, or if they just missed us because we weren't (yet) at 1000 questions at the time that they checked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is the batch of the websites that were selected before, at the time we did not have 1k questions.

Edit: We will have to request it now.

> Now, thanks to one of the amazing engineers on our Public Platform
> team (Adam Lear, take your bow), the CMs have a tool to allow us to do
> this without a developer. So in the future, if a site is eligible and
> ready to leave Beta, we can process those requests ad-hoc and in a
> more timely manner.

Comment: So we didn't ***ask*** to be left out. That's what I was wondering.

Comment: Yes, we're correct. I failed to find out what it means to request it ad-hoc.

Comment: Should we request it now or is there perhaps a good milestone for Cardano coming up that we can raise awareness with and align ourselves to?

Answer (score -1):

No, we simply did not meet other graduation requirements.

> In determining what sites were ready to graduate, we factored in site age (being in Public Beta for at least six months), having at least 1K open questions, and at least 70% of open questions having at least one upvoted answer. Sites needed to meet all three of these criteria in order to lose the Beta label. Based on these criteria, Cardano isn't ready to leave Public Beta yet.

Marek Mahut identified that we were just 50 questions short.

Comment: We met all of them. "(1) The site needed to be in public Beta for at least six months. (2) The site needed to have at least 1000 open questions. (3) At least 70% of the questions on the site needed to have at least one upvoted answer."

Comment: Please see my updated answer.

Comment: We have 1000+ questions and 80+ % answered. I'll look into it more later.

Comment: 50 questions short of what? We had 1000+ open questions and 80% of them answered when the other 59 sites  graduated.