# Can we transition out of Beta?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

This Stack Exchange is titled Cardano Beta. Why is there a "Beta" in it ? Wouldn't it be better to remove the "Beta" ?

Comment: Updated with a new answer

Comment: The process is under way.  Announcements will be made within the next 4 weeks.

Comment: Very exciting and congratulations to you all. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cardano stack exchange is a relatively new community on stackexchange (less than a year old). The [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/125174/cardano) page shows stats about different subcommunities such as ours. To graduate from alpha to beta and then to a full community certain requirements must be met, like total number of members, questions asked/answered, etc. I'm not sure what the exact requirements are, but if we keep up the good work I'm certain the high and mighty moderators will take notice and bump us up in due time.

Comment: thx, I did not know that it comes from Stack Exchange. So let's give our best. I certainly do.

Answer (score 5):

We satisfy the requirements to graduate out of Beta, but the diamond moderators will have to ask the SE staff to click the button(s) that will actually remove the Beta label.

You can see this related question: [Were we just missed, or did we ask to not graduate?](https://cardano.meta.stackexchange.com/q/84/149)

Also, I've informed the Stack Exchange staff [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/374111/391772), but it doesn't seem they care much about that. They have not left any comments, and the net score right now is only +1.

Basically we are just waiting for the diamond moderators to tell the staff, whenever they feel ready for us to graduate (or until enough community members make it clear that they want this to happen).

Comment: Thank you for the info. I hope the diamond moderators act soon. This "beta"-label looks strange and might give the impression to newcomers that the whole Cardano project is in beta phase.

Comment: Any idea how to do that? How to contact the staff? I did click everything possible, but cannot seem to find how do that.

Answer (score 1):

**We now meet the criteria for transition from beta to a full site.**

This question or variations on it have been asked several times now.  What little feedback we have had on it has been in favor of removing the Beta tag.

Nobody has suggested that it be retained.

I am in favour of it because we meet all the criteria and it gives all the users more of a reason to care and put the effort into raising the standard of the site.

*Note: the moderators are requesting that the community managers make the change and we will announce any progress in the "Loveplace" chat room.*